# Why does LiveReload not work in vue-cli project with Vagrant?

Tags: webpack, vagrant, vue.js

This is the first time I try vue-cli, to avoid installing npm-packages globally I use Vagrant.

**Vagrantfile**

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
 config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
 config.vm.hostname="vagrant"
 config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 4545
 config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/home/project"
 config.vm.provision :shell, path: "provision.sh", privileged: false
end
```

**provision.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# installing packages
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential libssl-dev -y

# installing nvm
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.32.1/install.sh | bash
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh

# installing node
nvm install node
nvm alias default node
nvm use node

# installing vue-cli
npm install -g vue-cli
```

**Init project and install**:
`vue init webpack my-project`
`npm install`

**Project structure**:

```
.
├── my-project
│   ├── build
│   ├── config
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── src
│   ├── static
│   └── test
├── provision.sh
└── Vagrantfile
```

After running the command *npm run dev* appear two warnings:

> (node:1787) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Exited with code 3
>
> (node:1787) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

But everything works

```
DONE  Compiled successfully in 4188ms
> Listening at http://localhost:8080
```

And I can see running project on my [localhost:4545](http://localhost:4545)

[image: Running project]

Then I edit *Hello.vue* file and save it. The browser does not change even if it is forced to restart.
In the terminal, also nothing changes it is in standby mode.

[image: The browser does not change]

The changes will be visible only if interrupt command `npm run dev` and run it again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After struggling long with this, I finally found out how to do that. Do this:

**/build/dev-server.js**

```
var devMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {
  publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
  quiet: false,
  stats: {
    colors: true,
    chunks: false
  },
  watchOptions: { //Add Polling
    aggregateTimeout: 300,
    poll: true
  }
})
```

Comment: My CPU usage went to 100% with those `watchOptions` so I backed it off to `poll: 1500, ignored: /node_modules/`.

Answer (score 7):

## Solution for Vue CLI 3.0.0

There are tow problems to solve:

1. vagrant machine doesn't get information about changes from host machine;
2. sockjs-node is probably configured for localhost.

#### Solution

1. set pooling for webpack;
2. set public address in webpack devServer configuration.

Create **vue.config.js** file in projects main directory:

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    devServer: {
        watchOptions: {
          ignored: ['node_modules'],
          aggregateTimeout: 300,
          poll: 1500
        },
        public: '192.168.56.132' // vagrant machine address
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You are a life saver.

Answer (score 4):

Notification via inotify requires the kernel to be aware of all relevant filesystem events, which is not always possible for networked filesystems such as NFS.

You will need polling so Webpack will check every few hundred milliseconds to see if your files have been updated.

```
 watchOptions: {
   poll: true
 }
```

to the bottom of your `webpack.dev.conf.js`

**EDIT**: LiveReload Chrome Extension listens on port 35729. Add the following to your Vagrantfile

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 35729, host: 35729
```

Comment: I added this option but no result
https://gist.github.com/in-in/02549afdc58d5ac9d1a2060a211e561e

Comment: It should work without any chrome extension.
@Julian wrote right answer below

Answer (score 0):

#### @vue/cli 4.2.3

Just happened to me with @vue/cli 4.2.3 on Vagrant.

First, I used the `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING` env variable. Ended up adding `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true` to `/etc/environment` in Vagrant guest during provision.

This allowed live changes to be seen in host's browser, but required refreshing. Setting `devServer.public` Vue configuration to `0.0.0.0:8080` solved that issue.

**TL;DR**

In */etc/environment*:

```
CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
```

In *vue.config.js*:

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    public: "0.0.0.0:8080"
  }
}
```